# How can I write my own LINQ provider to query some custom store?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am planning to write a LINQ provider, so that I can query data in a custom store - for example, let us say, some custom file format.

What is a good way to start? Any examples?

Comment: Googling "implementing IQueryable" will give you a good number of links to help you. The one I recommend starting with is this, which lists a number of blog posts on the various steps of implementing IQueryable: [http://blogs.msdn.com/mattwar/pages/linq-links.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattwar/pages/linq-links.aspx)

Comment: Here's a [good example](http://weblogs.asp.net/mehfuzh/archive/2007/10/04/writing-custom-linq-provider.aspx) of building a custom LINQ provider. You'd need to create a file parser that generates 'entity classes' based on the data contained within. You then create a context class that implements IQueryable. Then create a class that extends IQueryProvider. Override its .Execute() method to return an enumerated result.

Comment: I second casperOne's suggestion. Wayward WebLog is probably the best place for learning how to build custom provider. Also there is a useful article + source code: [LINQ to Active Directory (formerly known as LINQ to LDAP)](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2007/11/25/linq-to-active-directory-formerly-known-as-linq-to-ldap-is-here.aspx)

Comment: Disagree with "closed as not constructive". This is a fine question who's answer I am interested in. casperOne's linq link (see what I did there?) is a good start.